# Automatic Indexing Assets

Tags: assets

Is automatic indexing possible?

I want to be able to ftp files up and not have to worry about going into control panel and indexing to get them to pull through on the frontend.

This wouldnt be a problem if it was just me. BUT other people will be uploading to the directory and "they dont want to be going into the control panel and indexing everytime"...

Thanks for any help.